# Warnings during kernel compiling

Tags: kernel, compiling, compiler

I'm compiling custom kernel and during the process I'm getting warnings such as:

```
drivers/isdn/hardware/eicon/message.c:6115:1: warning: the frame size of 1184 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
```

The part

```
warning: the frame size of XXXX bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
```

are always the same.

I'm find out that it is some compiler-enforced limit for the architecture upon which I'm building.

Should I be worried? If so, anyone have idea how to resolve this?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit.

Comment: You are almost always safe ignoring warnings.

Comment: Is this means that some parts are not successfully compiled?

Comment: No , they are warnings not errors. You can report them upstream to kernel.org.